# SSH key on Ubuntu 20 doesn't work with any Git Repo

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04.02LTS. I installed Git, generated a new `.ssh` with this example from [DigitalOcean](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent), after which I added the new key (public) to my github, bitbucket and private git repo, and it fails with all three with the usual message: `Permission denied (publickey).`

I checked that the key was added to the agent, and that the agent was running.

git version 2.25.1

To test, i took my laptop running 16.04lts, generated a new key, added it to github (waited 5min) and cloned a repo without issues.

Edit: run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key git@github.com`  and it was a pass.

Answer (score 0):

First, if your key is not using a default name, you would need to declare it in `~/.ssh/config` file in order for Git to use it.

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key

cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin gh:<user>/<repo>
git ls-remote
```

A simpler test:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

Check if you get a Welcome message.

---

If it is still not working, I would first test it:

- with a RSA key
- without a passphrase, to avoid any ssh-agent step (again, for testing)

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/newKey
  ```